# Spivaks proof chapter 7

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, proof-explanation, self-learning

Hi I am a student working through Spivak Calculus chapter 7 theorem 9 pg.123 and I can't understand his use of the triangle inequality in his theorem.

The theorem states:
If $n$ is odd, then any equation
$$
\ x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\cdots+a^0
$$
has a root.

proof: we would like to prove that $f$ is sometimes positive and sometimes negative. The
intuitive idea is that for large $|x|$, the function is very much like $g(x) = x^n$ and,
since $n$ is odd, this function is positive for large positive $x$ and negative for large
negative $x$. A little algebra is all we need to make this intuitive idea work.

$$
f(x) = x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\cdots+a^0 = x^n \left(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n}\right)
$$

Note that
$$
\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n} \right|\le \frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|x|}+\frac{|a_{n-2}|}{|x^2|}+\cdots+\frac{|a_{0}|}{|x^n|}
$$

Consequently if we choose $x$ satisfying
$$
|x|>1,2n|a_{n-1}|,\ldots,2n|a_0| 
$$

Then

$$
\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{a_0}{x^n} \right|\le \frac{1}{
2n}+\frac{1}{2n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}$$ what i do not understand is how can we say that the summation of these terms is still $\le\frac{1}{2n}$ surely it is strictly less than $\frac{1}{2n}$ and never equal to as I am taking x to be smaller?.

Comment: Don't you mean $\frac{1}{2n}+...+\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Also it doesn't really matter because $<1/2n$ implies $\leq 1/2n$

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916908/error-in-spivaks-proof-that-an-odd-degree-polynomial-has-a-root

Comment: @matias ures $\le$ and $< $  are 2 different things they don't mean the same thing

Comment: In general, $a<b\implies a≤b$.  The other way round is, of course, false in general.

Comment: @Thehomeschooler Of course $\leq$ and $<$ doesn't mean the same thing, Matías is trying to saying that you have $\leq$ once you have $<$.

Comment: Sorry but What do you mean by other way round ?

Comment: What I'm saying is this theorem uses $\leq 1/2n$ to prove the theorem, say you prove $<1/2n$ since this implies $\leq 1/2n$, the proposition $\leq 1/2n$ is still true.